# How to change the default mail template for subscriptions module

Tags: 7, emails, notifications

It's probably a silly question but I just can't find the answer: Where can I change the default email template for the [Subscriptions](https://drupal.org/project/subscriptions) email? I'm using Drupal 7 and installed the module Subscriptions.

I would expect to change the mail templates at `http://[mydomain]/admin/config/system/mail-edit`. However at this location I only can add language translations for 4 languages which I've enabled but not the default email templates.

Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Comment: Did you look for a template in the modules folder?

Comment: No I didn't. Isn't there a method to change the template with the normal Drupal user(admin) interface? If this is not possible, at which path and file do I find the default template?

Answer (score 1):

There is no template but you can solve this by adding the mail_edit module to your site. Here's the notes from the documentation:

http://drupal.org/node/344030#Configuration

(scroll down to "Mail Templates")

> If you have installed and enabled the mail_edit module then you can go
>   to admin/build/mail_edit to edit the mail templates.

Comment: I have installed and enabled the "mail editer" module version 7.x-1.0-rc1. However when I go to /admin/build/mail_edit I end up at exactly the same regular /admin screen without any specific reference to editing the mail templates(but the URL shows me that im at /admin/build/mail_edit.)

Comment: did you check that the current user has permissions to this module? flush cache after installing to make sure menu hooks update?

Comment: Im logged in as admin (which also installed the module) and cleared the cache. Still no joy. I can make a screendump but it is as simple as going to /admin . It is exactly the same page I see. Anybody an idea?

Comment: ok - looks like the drupal instructions are referring to drupal 6.x - not 7.x. If you ever have problems with menus not loading and you have done the two steps above, the next step is to look at the source code of the module and look for where they are defining the menu hooks. In this case, under "mail_edit_menu()", the  correct path is: admin/config/system/mail-edit

Comment: Hi Schnippy, ok this makes sense. I'm familiar with the page admin/config/system/mail-edit. It is the page which in my original problem description contains the options to create translations for 4 different languages: For each template I see "Add en Add nl Add fr Add de". As explained I don't see an option to change the mail template, only adding translations for the original?

Comment: Got an answer of the maintainer of that module: (http://drupal.org/node/1827508) _The ability to change the default template has just been added in #1821292: Implement an editable default template. See the -dev version._

Comment: I know this is a very old thread but thought it worth to mention that on a D7 site that does not have i18n, the page at admin/config/system/mail-edit shows a row for Subscriptions Mail | .DEFAULT, for which the Edit link goes to /admin/config/system/mail-edit/subscriptions_mail_.DEFAULT/en